# Regex match multiple times in one line

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I need to find matches for strings beginning with a date/time and ending with "Additional comments". When two or more matches are in the same line, the whole line is returned. I know this is due to the greedy quantifier and a group construct is needed. I am new to Regex and would appreciate help and also advice on how to improve what I have done so far. I have followed multiple examples but cannot work it out for my case.

This is what I have so far. The except '(' is for cases where Additional comments should not be matched.
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[^(]+Additional comments

This is an example line with the issue:
2018-04-19 02:57:57 - John Smith Additional commentsHi Meredith,As agreed ticket is assigned to your queue.John2018-04-19 02:11:57 - Meredith Berkenstock Additional commentsCan you please describe how the report should populate data for invoice # 4257032018-04-19 02:08:27 - John Smith Additional commentsHi Meredith,ticket is assigned back to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If greedy is the problem, you can try using `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[^(]+?Additional comments`. `?` after `+` turns it into non-greedy, https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax.

I am not quite sure what output is required, and I would suggest to format the question so that spaces and newlines are clear. Include the current output and required output as well.

Comment: Thank you so much user12036762, that is what was needed. FYI I got there in the end after a few videos on YouTube this morning and I am sorry if I have troubled you.